# Append key, value from dict to another dict based on match. For later use in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dicts and I want to merge dicts that have the same key, value for later use in a dataframe.
*PS: I don't know if pandas can handle this by itself. Maybe it's not necessary to append the dicts.*

My list of dicts:

```
[{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'São Paulo', 'description': '"Estado de São Paulo"'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'description': '"Estado do Rio de Janeiro"'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'population': '12345'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'work_force': '2345'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Paraná', 'description': '"Estado do Paraná"'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Santa Catarina', 'description': '"Estado de Santa Catarina"'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Santa Catarina', 'population': '54321'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Santa Catarina', 'work_force': '4321'}]
```

Output when I create the dataframe:

```
  country           State                 description population work_force
0  Brazil       São Paulo       "Estado de São Paulo"        NaN        NaN
1  Brazil  Rio de Janeiro  "Estado do Rio de Janeiro"        NaN        NaN
2  Brazil  Rio de Janeiro                         NaN      12345        NaN
3  Brazil  Rio de Janeiro                         NaN        NaN       2345
4  Brazil          Paraná          "Estado do Paraná"        NaN        NaN
5  Brazil  Santa Catarina  "Estado de Santa Catarina"        NaN        NaN
6  Brazil  Santa Catarina                         NaN      54321        NaN
7  Brazil  Santa Catarina                         NaN        NaN       4321
```

What I need:

```
  country           State                 description population work_force
0  Brazil       São Paulo       "Estado de São Paulo"        NaN        NaN
1  Brazil  Rio de Janeiro  "Estado do Rio de Janeiro"      12345       2345
2  Brazil          Paraná          "Estado do Paraná"        NaN        NaN
3  Brazil  Santa Catarina  "Estado de Santa Catarina"      54321       4321
```

The desired output is achieved when I merge the dicts:

```
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'description': '"Estado do Rio de Janeiro"', 'population': '12345', 'work_force': '2345'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Paraná', 'description': '"Estado do Paraná"'},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'State': 'Santa Catarina', 'description': '"Estado de Santa Catarina"', 'population': '54321', 'work_force': '4321'}]
```

So I'm looking for ways of merging thoses dicts into a single on based on the key "State".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes pandas can handle this. group on country and state and take the first value:

```
df.groupby(["country","State"],sort=False).first().reset_index()
```